# How do I implement a script into button in html file?

Tags: javascript, button

I have an operational script that can be run in Firebug console, but I want to launch it using a html button.

How do I do this?

Comment: `document.getElementById('[your-button-id]').onclick = [your-function];`

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript

Comment: @Kevin Boucher I've tried your code but it didn't work. Here's the script: `javascript:ukScript="http://ftp.innogames.net/~tracey/script/fluffy88_switchVillageN.js";s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.src=ukScript+'?'+Math.floor((new Date()).valueOf()/604800000);document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);void 0;`

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I'm using frames. First frame for buttons that should activate this script and the second one is and iframe for one site. It looks like buttons from frame A, don't "see" in frame B?

Comment: The code you sent won't even run on my console.

Comment: @Raphael_ It's for a game, that you have to login to make it run. It works in my console. I just tested it on site, but it won't work on iframe.

Comment: For some reason it's failing when trying to concat ukScript with the date thingy. Tried on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ok, on the code you pasted on the site: There seems to be some kind of accent (?) on the `l`, on `appendChild`, which caused the code not to run. Try copy pasting it to a text-editor and trying to delete the l, you'll see it takes 2 backspaces to erase it.

Comment: @Raphael_ Hmm, I just tested and I don't have that problem. I'm 100% certain now that the code doesn't work because an iframe. Is there a way to press the button in frame A.html and launch it in frame B.html?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/fun-with-frames-script-between-frames/5077439

Comment: You can only target elements in another frame if they are on the same domain. Otherwise you will be blocked by cross-site scripting security filters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @Dale That's why it only works when I put script in Firebug console on site, and not when I'm running frames and iframe of existing site from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access properties from other frames, you can do so in the similar pattern:

```
// This is our frame 1
function doSomething() {
    // ...
}

// This is our frame 2
parent.frames[0].doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. Could you check the comments below my question please?